# "apt-get update" with new added repo is working but packages are not found when trying to install

Tags: apt, debian-jessie

I'm trying to install GitLab on a virtual machine running Debian Jessie.

I have added the GitLab repo by running:
`curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash`

Everything worked fine so far. Even `apt-get update` works fine. There are entries in `/var/lib/apt/lists` for this new repo now. But the package is not found when running `apt-get install gitlab-ee`. Even `apt-cache search gitlab` doesn't find anything.

`/etc/apt/sources.list` has got the following content:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20160123-18:00]/ jessie main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

The new repo is listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ee.list`:

```
# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee

deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian/ jessie main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee/debian/ jessie main
```

Any ideas?

---

`apt-get update` output (sorry - it's in german: Holen = Get)

```
root@host:~# apt-get update
OK   https://deb.nodesource.com jessie InRelease
OK   http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
OK   https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Sources
OK   https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main i386 Packages
Holen: 1 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 2 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
OK   https://packages.gitlab.com jessie InRelease
Holen: 3 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 4 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
OK   https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Sources
Holen: 5 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
OK   https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main i386 Packages
Holen: 6 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 7 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 8 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 9 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 10 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 11 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 12 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 13 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 14 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 15 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 16 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 17 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 18 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 19 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 20 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE
Holen: 21 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 22 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 23 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-de
Holen: 24 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Holen: 25 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en
Holen: 26 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Holen: 27 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Holen: 28 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE [162 B]
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de_DE
Holen: 29 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de [162 B]
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-de
Holen: 30 https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie InRelease
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie Release
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources
Holen: 31 http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [11,8 kB]
Holen: 32 http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [3.688 B]
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie/main Sources
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie/main i386 Packages
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie/main Translation-de_DE
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie/main Translation-de
OK   http://ftp.de.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
OK   http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
OK   http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main i386 Packages
OK   http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Es wurden 15,5 kB in 10 s geholt (1.505 B/s).
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt-get update`?

Comment: @Halfgaar yes sure. I have added the output to my answer. Btw.: I have got the same problem with the nodesource-repo. So it seems to be a general issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official i386 NETINST Binary-1 20160123-18:00]/ jessie main`

I think it because you're running debian 32 bit, there is no package available for 32bit for Debian https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee

you might need to install from source and compile it for 32 bit or upgrade your system to 64bit.